# Docker warm with nginx proxy pass and firewalld

Tags: docker, nginx, firewalld

I have a Docker swarm network with one server acting as a load balancer running nginx in a container. This container uses nginx proxy pass to forward requests to other internal servers on an interface that’s private and uses specific ports

So for example there may be an incoming request on port 443, the nginx container then forwards this to one of the internal servers on day 192.168.0.2 on port 3000 where the Docker swarm lives and listens on 3000 to serve the website via another nginx and php containers.

It all works fine until I enable firewalld and I end up with a 502 error.

So I installed firewalld on the balancing server and assigned the internal adapter to the trusted zone and the external adapter to the public zone. All ports on public zone closed except 80,443 and 22.

At this point I now get a bad gateway error but when I turn the firewall off all works fine again. So it seems the incoming request works as it’s hitting the balancer nginx container but somehow it no longer forwards the traffic on the internal network.

Looking for ideas on why this would happen? If the internal ip addresses are on the adapter that’s attached to the trusted zone then I can’t understand why they stopped working

Comment: Are you able to find any solution to this? I am facing the exact issue. But I didn't change anything in the firewall config, just starting the firewall with the default config is making the Nginx service inaccessible.

Restarting the docker service fixed the issue. But

Comment: I am looking for a permanent fix as whenever the firewall service restarts, docker should be restarted in the server which needs manual attention.